# SpannableStringBuilder breaks InputFilter interface?

Tags: android, android-edittext, input-filter

**Summary:  SpannableStringBuilder erroneously uses 'end' parameter of InputFilter::filter(...) to put the length of 'source'**

---

**Background**

InputFilter has the following method:

```
abstract CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
```

According to the official documentation:

> This method is called when the buffer is going to replace the range
>   dstart … dend of dest with the new text from the range start … ***end*** of
>   source.

The parameter we are interested in is ***end***

**Suppoorting Evidence:**

1) A robolectric unit test (results are the same when tested on an actual android device):

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class playground
{
  static int mTestNumber;      //so know which testcase is being run in filter();

  @Test
  public void test_SpannableStringBuilder()
  {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb;
    InputFilter inputFilter;

    inputFilter = new InputFilter()
    {

      @Override
      public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
      {
        int[] expected,
              results;
        results= new int[] {start, end, dstart, dend};

        switch (mTestNumber)
        {
          case 0:     //"0123" appended to default initialization (empty string?)
            expected= new int[] {0, 3, 0, 0};
            Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, results); // fails since end=4.
            break;
        }
        return null;
      }
    };


    mTestNumber= 0;
    ssb= new SpannableStringBuilder("");         //internally stored as 2 chars" "0\0"
    ssb.setFilters((new InputFilter[] {inputFilter}));
    ssb.append("0123");

    return;
  }   
}     ///END CLASS///
```

(start,end) should be (0,3)

But when the test is run:

(start,end) = (0,4)

It appears that ***end*** is returning the length

**Further digging:**

Looking in SpannableStringBuilder we have:

```
SpannableStringBuilder   append(CharSequence text)
```

> Convenience for replace(length(), length(), text, 0, text.length())

and then

```
SpannableStringBuilder   replace(int start, int end, CharSequence tb, int tbstart, int tbend)
```

> Replaces the specified range (st…en) of text in this Editable with a
>   copy of the slice start…end from source.

Notice:

1) append() puts text.length() into tbend (**I believe this is the source of the bug**)

2) replace() documentation has the wrong parameter names

---

**Thoughts**

This looks to be such a glaring error, especially since it basically makes InputFilter unusable with EditText except for the most simple cases. I haven't been able to find anything about this bug. I have trouble believing it hasn't come up before. Am I missing something here?

Comment: are you getting repeated text in your `EditText`?

Comment: I may have. I'm aware that it is another issue. Have you ran into the issue in the above question?

Comment: Do you expect position of last character to be in *end*? I beleive it works like that by design. Empty string is a good example: end would be -1

Comment: I expect that it follows the InputFilter javadoc:

Comment: That is the expectation according to the InputFilter javadoc ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html ). The problem is SpannableStringBuilder  does not return the position of the last character in **end**. It returns the LENGTH of text being copied to **end**. Is that clear?

Comment: I got your point. Could you please provide a real-life example, that doesn't work? I've implemented an `InputFilter` in my project recently, and it works just fine.

Comment: The robolectric test case in the question demonstrates the bug. I am unclear what you desire. With all due respect, your comments do not seem to address the question asked at all. I wrote this question to have the issue evidenced above replicated or disproved.

Comment: I just asked you for more information. The test case you provided is abstracted, not a real case [from a real project]. It is not clear for me why end should point to last character. I always thought that start/end are sort of cursor position. From that point everything works as it should. If you still think it's a bug, post an issue to android issue tracker http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: Don't the javadocs for InputFilter make it clear?

"This method is called when the buffer is going to replace the range dstart … dend of dest with the new text from the range start … end of source."

How can the cursor be at start and end? 
I posted the bug report already https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62407&q=SpannableStringBuilder%20breaks%20InputFilter%20interface%3F&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
Unfortunately it doesn't seem that they are monitored

Comment: Hey @Ian I've been stuck in the same issue from the past 2 days now. here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230003/indexoutofboundexception-setspan-2-2-ends-beyond-length-1 . Did you find any solution to this problem ?