# indexoutofboundexception : setSpan (2...2) ends beyond length 1

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

I've a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` custom control in which I am creating chips text, when user presses the space key.

I do not want the user to input space initially when the textbox is empty so I put an `inputFilter` in order to prevent user from putting space initially.

Here's the Filter Code:

```
private void RestrictUselessSpaces(){
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 

        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                if (Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) { 

                    if(!getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        return " "; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                } 
        } 
        return null; 
        } 
};  

    setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
}
```

Somehow when I comment `RestrictUselessSpaces` function. It works fine. But when this function runs. Than if I try to enter space after a character. It gives me the `indexoutofboundexception` error. Here's my code where I get the error.

```
public void setChips(String s){

    if(s.contains(" ") && !s.trim().equals("")) // check space in string
    {
        this.chips = s.trim().split(" ");

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(getText());
        // split string wich comma
        int x =0;
        // loop will generate ImageSpan for every country name separated by comma
        for(String c : chips){
            // inflate chips_edittext layout 
            LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            TextView textView = (TextView) lf.inflate(R.layout.chips_edittext, null);
            textView.setText(c); // set text


            setFlags(textView, c); // set flag image
            // capture bitmapt of genreated textview
            int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            textView.measure(spec, spec);
            textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(), textView.getMeasuredHeight());
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
            canvas.translate(-textView.getScrollX(), -textView.getScrollY());
            textView.draw(canvas);
            textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap cacheBmp = textView.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            textView.destroyDrawingCache();  // destory drawable
            // create bitmap drawable for imagespan
            BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
            bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0,bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
            // create and set imagespan 
            ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable),x ,x + c.length() , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);    
            x = x+ c.length() +1;
        }

        // set chips span 
        setText(ssb);


        // move cursor to last 
        setSelection(s.length());
    }

}
```

The line `ssb.setSpan` is causing the problem but when I debug the code. The debugger runs this line without giving me any kind of exception. Error occurs after the execution of this function which is making it more hard for me to identify what actually is causing the problem.

And here's my logcat:

```
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461): Process: com.example.twitter, PID: 18461
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (2 ... 2) ends beyond length 1
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:94)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at com.example.libraries.ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview.setChips(ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview.java:281)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at com.example.libraries.ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview$1.onTextChanged(ChipsMultiAutoCompleteTextview.java:192)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7429)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7488)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9203)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:675)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:197)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:183)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:279)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
08-10 20:04:19.253: E/AndroidRuntime(18461):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try to replace this code ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable),x ,c.length()-1 , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: if your ssb size is 1 you cannot set span from offset 2 to offset 2, btw spans with length == 0 as in your case, behave strangely on some android versions

Comment: @Haresh replace with that ?

Comment: @pskink ssb size 1 means the length of the text i suppose. The value of `x` is 0 while the value of `c.length()` is 1 in my case if i enter only one character. so `start=0 and end=1` I don't think anything is exceeding 1 here. I intentionally put the `-1` in the third argument in order to check if it works, but it still doesn't.

Comment: Can you please simply remove x+ from your code and let me is it working ? And please keep in mind which regular exp. your using for split which is not include in splited array so plz check value of splited array then you getting exect idea.

Comment: Also this seems suspicious `x = x+ c.length() +1;` if your string is "a b" you will be calling `setSpan(..., 0, 0)` and `setSpan(..., 2, 2)`...

Comment: no, the value of x is 2 (... setSpan (2…2) ends beyond length 1)

Comment: @Haresh removed `x+` still getting the error

Comment: I only enter one character `g` than press the space button which runs this code. When I enter one character. The value of `x` is `0` while `c.length()` gives 1. The error says `SetSpan(2..2)` which I don't get why. Because `x+c.length() = 1` instead of 2. The line also runs fine while debugging. But after returning from this function I get the error. The error has something to do with the `RestrictUselessSpaces` function, because when I comment it. The code works fine.

Comment: Log.d those two params of setSpan(): "start", "end" and ssb.length()

Comment: Please check c length becz may second array element is null or empty.

Comment: @pskink @Haresh after logging . `ssb.length() = 2` , `Value of x = 0` , `c.length() = 1`

Comment: see the source of your error: http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java#checkRange

Answer (score -1):

try using this

```
setSelection(s.length() - 1);
```